# How can I claim a Seniors' discount at a Residence Inn?

Tags: hotels

I made a booking today at the Residence inn by Marriott in Gaithersburg but there was no place at the booking to put that my husband and I are senior citizens. How can I claim a discount? My trip is in April 2021.

Comment: What makes you think there _is_ a senior discount?

Comment: How about calling them on the phone and asking?

Comment: Did you book on the official Marriott website or through a 3rd party? The official website offers a dropdown box with discounts, and "Senior Discount" is one item there.

Comment: Which Gaithersburg? Maryland? Most hotels are independently owned and operated franchisees, and contacting the property directly rather than going through the corporate office can yield better results.